# How can I resolve kubernetes CrashLoopBackOff problem?

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl

I wanted to connect echo server and client. So I built images of them and pushed them to docker hub. These are Dockerfiles of them.

<server Dockerfile
`

```
FROM docker.io/python:3.9.15
RUN apt-get update
WORKDIR /me
COPY server.py .
EXPOSE 65456
CMD ["python", "/me/server.py"]
```

`

<client Dockerfile
`

```
FROM docker.io/python:3.9.15
RUN apt-get update
WORKDIR /you
COPY client.py .
EXPOSE 8080
CMD ["python", "/you/client.py"]
```

`

And I wrote .yaml to make a pod and connect them in k8s. This is the yaml file.

`

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: assign3
  labels:
    app: assign3
  
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: assign3-pod
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: assign3-pod
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: server
        image: docker.io//*myserverimagename/*/:1.0
        ports:
        - containerPort: 65456

      - name: client
        image: docker.io//*myclientimagename/*:1.0
```

`

Server is working well, but everytime I try, client leaves this message, "back-off 5m0s restarting failed container=client pod=assign3-859cf44595-clvzs_default(aed6633b-adf9-44c5-ad54-a60e8de48d20)" , and its ready and start status is fail because of "CrashLoopBackOff".

This is an event log; I found it from minikube dashboard.

[(https://i.stack.imgur.com/p4msJ.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p4msJ.png)

I tried to rebuild client image and pushed it again to docker hub, but I couldn't resolve it.... please help me smart guys..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check or share the logs of the client container using kubectl command

```
kubectl logs <pod_name> <container_name>
```

Comment: When I tried, I got a message "Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/you/client.py", line 10, in <module>
    clientSocket.connect((HOST, PORT))
ConnectionRefusedError: [Errno 111] Connection refused
". Is it a port problem..?

Comment: ok, On the basis of the log, it means something is wrong at the application level, not the Kubernetes container level. Can you try to make your server and client connection using the script manually?